# CSS Grid effect issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I need some help on creating a grid...
I want to make it look like this website:
https://www.domo.com/company/executives

Here is what fund when viewing the page source:
http://jsfiddle.net/o45LLsxd/

```
<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope"><div class="biogrid ng-scope">
 <!-- ngRepeat: executive in notSorted(executives) --><div ng-repeat="executive in notSorted(executives)" ng-init="executive = executives[executive]" class="ng-scope">
<div class="biogrid-tile active" id="joshjames" biotile="">
    <img src="https://www.domo.com/assets/images/executives/josh-james.jpg" alt="Josh James">
    <div class="biogrid-info">
        <div class="biogrid-name ng-binding">Josh James</div>
        <div class="biogrid-title ng-binding">Founder, CEO &amp; Chairman of the Board</div>
        <div class="biogrid-handle ng-binding">
            <i class="icon-domofont-twitter-reg"></i> @joshjames
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="biogrid-bio">
        <div class="biogrid-name ng-binding">Josh James</div>
        <div class="biogrid-title ng-binding">Founder, CEO &amp; Chairman of the Board</div>
        <div class="biogrid-handle ng-binding">
            <i class="icon-domofont-twitter-reg"></i> @joshjames
        </div>
        <p class="ng-binding">Josh founded Domo in 2010 to help CEOs and other leaders change the way they do business and obtain value from the tens of billions of dollars spent on traditional business intelligence systems. Before founding Domo, Josh was the CEO of Omniture, which he co-founded in 1996 and took public in 2006; and from 2006-2009, he was the youngest CEO of a publicly traded company.</p>
        <div class="hidden-bio ng-binding">&lt;p class='bio-intro'&gt;Josh founded Domo in 2010 to help CEOs and other leaders change the way they do business and obtain value from the tens of billions of dollars spent on traditional business intelligence systems. Before founding Domo, Josh was the CEO of Omniture, which he co-founded in 1996 and took public in 2006; and from 2006-2009, he was the youngest CEO of a publicly traded company.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Omniture was the number one returning venture investment out of 1,008 venture capital investments in 2004, as well as the number two performing technology IPO of 2006. Omniture was also the fastest or second fastest-growing public company for three consecutive years. In 2009, Josh facilitated Omniture's $1.8 billion sale to Adobe.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Josh serves as a member of the World Economic Forum's Young Global Leaders, a worldwide community of individuals committed to, and recognized for, their proven leadership and potential in shaping the future.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;In 2012, the Utah Tech Council inducted him into its Hall of Fame and Mountain West Capital Network named Josh its Entrepreneur of the Year. In 2011, Fortune Magazine recognized him as one of its "40 Under 40: Ones to Watch" and, in 2009, as one of its "40 Under 40" top business executives. He was named the 2006 Ernst &amp; Young Entrepreneur of the Year and Brigham Young University's Technology Entrepreneur of the Decade.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Josh is the founder of CEO.com, a resource to help founders and CEOs stay up to date with what's happening at the executive level across top industries, as well as stay armed with the latest leadership strategies and best practices. He also founded Silicon Slopes, a non-profit initiative designed to promote the interests of Utah's high-tech industry.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Josh has six daughters.&lt;/p&gt;</div>
        <a href="#joshjames" class="btn btn-link">read more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to get the css but it seems like they are using AngularJs which I have never worked with before; I'm a noob btw...

So my concern is how would I make that grid by just using html,css, and js... or AngularJs if you can show me how it works. Thanks to those of you who are helping me out with the issue that I have had :)

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: You just need the grid? let me create a jsfiddle

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian Yes, I just need a grid that functions like the one form http://domo.com/company/executives Thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Do This With CSS `vw` unit. take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Svvift/5zu374z7/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#grid {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#grid .cell {
    width: 33.333333vw;
    height: 33.333333vw;
    background: white;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that's so close to what I want, but how would I add the effect when I hover my mouse over? I want a title that's always showing, and when you hover your mouse over it will show more text.

Comment: you should learn about css events and jquery perhaps. ask another question about that and let me know to give you the answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! any place reconmanded to learn these?

Comment: yes. 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp
http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/html-css/CSS3-Hover-Effects/index.html
http://designshack.net/articles/css/joshuajohnson-2/

Comment: these are 4 links. hope these help